# How to set Project Settings with Configuration specific values in VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, configuration-files, buildconfiguration

**Is there a way to set Project Settings with Build Configuration specific values in VS2013?**
I need to set different values for a WebServiceURL setting from one Build Configuration to another (say MSSQL configuration vs Oracle configuration).

I saw both a preprocessor assembly configuration using #if DEBUG and an afterbuild config file overwrite approach, but the former does not allow for custom configuration names or more than 2 configurations while the later involves copying files after build rather than the quick and easy edit in the Project Properties > Settings page.

Is there something similar to Web.config Transformation available to App.config maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin, it works for me. And you can transform any xml-file.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859

Comment: Sounds like a good extension. Will give it a try and post back how it worked out.

Comment: I **ended up using SlowCheetah**, it worked out - w/ changes to my code:    
- _convert my `applicationSettings` to `appSettings`_ (applicationSetting would not read updated values even though they were updated in the config file, pb because applicationSettings are synchronized; tried Reloading and other options - no luck)  
- _Configure `appSettings` in a separate config file_ maintained in the main project and linked in my unit testing project. Different than applicationSettings, appSettings are read from the unit test project config even though the class is defined in the main project